# Is it worth upgrading to VS2010 Ultimate to take advantage of the advanced debugging features?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010

I am currently using VS2010 Premium, and have heard that the debugging in Ultimate is so much better. Is it really worth upgrading to Ultimate to take advantage of the new debugging features they've included? Or is it marketing hype and not really usable for every day development scenarios?

I believe the feature is called IntelliTrace.

Comment: What languages/technologies are you using?

Comment: C#, SQL, XML, XSLT, ASMX, MOSS mainly

Comment: Wow - I didn't realize until I just now looked how big the price jump between 'Premium' and 'Ultimate' is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you work in a team? Do you get bugs reported to you by a tester, and then you can't repro them? Would it save you a lot of time to be able to "debug" through the actual setup the tester had - see their values and execution path? Or perhaps you work with another developer. Would you like to be able to set a bunch of breakpoints and leave "notes" in the code (pinned data tips) and then export them and give them to the other developer, saying "the bug we're looking for is in your part of the code".

If those scenarios cause you pain now, you want Ultimate. If you work alone, it's possible that IntelliTrace alone will make you want Ultimate. It is cool to "time travel" in the debugger.

Comment: Hi Kate, I tested the ability to travel through the history of debugging, but it wasn't what I expected, it takes snapshots of variable values at given times, but doesn't let you step back unfortunately.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "step back" but according to what I mean by it (move the "current line" back and see what the variables were then) you can. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336126.aspx for screenshots etc. I have done this where you have an exception and go back in and rewind till the point where things started to go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you are heavily working on Linq to SQL / Linq to entities then IntelliTrace feature will surely helpful.

Then you should upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

they have quite a few named advantages in this site http://c.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/csharp-l/whats-new-in-vs2010-and-is-it-worth-upgrading-3531098#M3669289

Answer (score 0):

IntelliTrace is the only way to download the crash and other event logs from Windows Azure. The devFabric isnt quite a 100% representation of the azure deployment environment. I have used the Intellitrace to find deployment flubs quickly. When everything takes 20 minutes to deploy, having a tool that saves you 1 or 2 deployment cycles pays for itself quickly.